# using the same controller for two states with ui-router can't make the data change instantaneously

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am new to angular, and I am having problems figuring this out. How can I make the binding data change without reloading the app.

```
//routes.js

  function MainRouter ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $stateProvider
    .state ('About', {
      url: '/about',
      templateUrl: 'js/about/about.html',
      controller: 'adminController',
      controllerAs: 'vm'
    })
    .state ('Admin', {
      url: '/admin',
      templateUrl: 'js/admin/admin.html',
      controller: 'adminController',
      controllerAs: 'vm'
    })
  }
```

I am trying to build a simple website with an 'admin console' that allows the user to change the content of the pages. The app is working but is not updating the content without re-loading the app...

The '/admin' route has the inputs to change the data through a function that updates the database.I load the content from the database when the page is loading so changes stay when users log out, but I am also binding the data so you can see the changes in real-time.

```
//admin.html

  <div class='about-page-options>
    <form name='changeAboutTitle' ng-submit='vm.changeContent()'>
      <div class='about-page-options-title input-field'>
        <input type='text' ng-model='vm.changeContentInput.aboutTitle'>
        <label>title</label>
      </div>
      <div>
        <button class='btn' type='submit'>Change</button>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
```

The controller has the changeContent function.

```
//adminController.js
  function adminController($http, Upload, adminService){
    var vm=this
    vm.loadContent=loadContent
    vm.aboutTitle = ''
    vm.changeContent = changeContent
    vm.changeContentInput = {}


//Load Content Page from database when loading the app
    function loadContent () {
      console.log('load content triggered')
      $http({
        method:'GET',
        url:'/api/content'
      }).then(
        function(res){
          vm.aboutTitle = res.data[0].aboutTitle
        }
      );
    };
    loadContent()

function changeContent () {
  adminService.changeContent(vm.changeContentInput).then(function (res) {
    vm.aboutTitle = res.data.aboutTitle
  })
 }
}
})();
```

In this case, the content I want to change is vm.aboutTitle. The app changes it, I can see it when I reload the page. But because vm.aboutTitle is also included in the navbar I can see it all the time and I see that doesn't change immediately , I guess this happens because the admin controller I am modifying is not the same that the one linked to the nav bar, so the big question here is how to change data in one controller and also change in other instances of the same controller.

```
    //index.html
<html ng-app='myapp'>
      <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8'>
        <title>myapp</title>    
      </head>

  <body>
    <div class="navbar-fixed" ng-controller='adminController as vm'>
      <nav>
        <div class='nav-bar'>
          <div class='brand-logo'>
            <div id='logo'>MyLogo</div>
          </div>
          <ul>
            <li><a ui-sref='home' id='home'>Home</a></li>
            <li><a ui-sref='About'>{{vm.aboutTitle}}</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </div>

    <div ui-view></div>


</body>
</html>
```

I also created a service just in case it helps me to solve this but so far no luck. Any advice???

```
//adminService.js
function adminService ($http) {
    var service={
      changeContent: changeContent
    }
    return service;

    function changeContent (data) {
      console.log(data)
      var promise = $http({
        method: 'PUT',
        url: 'api/content',
        data: data,
      }).then (
        function (res) {
          return res;
        }
      )
      return promise
    };
  }
```

And

```
//app.js
(function() {
  angular.module('myapp', ['ui.router', 'ngResource']);
})();
```

Comment: Please try to make a minimal and complete example of your issue as explained in the help center: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

Every route that use the same controller will create a new instance of it.
In general, controllers are not designed to keep state.

If you look for a good read about design, [Todd's one is good](https://github.com/toddmotto/angular-styleguide).

Answer (score 0):

if you want to share or use the same controller with different states you can use [this jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/quethzel/789Ks/730/).

HTML

```
<nav> 
    <a ui-sref="state1">State 1</a>
    <a ui-sref="state2">State 2</a>
    <a ui-sref="state3">State 3</a>
</nav>

<div ui-view></div>
```

AngularJs

```
var myApp = angular.module("myApp",[ "ui.router", "AppCtrls"]);

var routeTemplate1 = "<p>Content of State 1 with Ctrl1</p>";
var routeTemplate2 = "<p>Content of State 2 with Ctrl2</p>";
var routeTemplate3 = "<p>Content of State 3 with Ctrl1</p>";

myApp.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){
    $stateProvider
        .state("state1", {
        url: "#",
        template: routeTemplate1,
        controller: "Ctrl1"
      })
      .state("state2", {
        url: "#",
        template: routeTemplate2,
        controller: "Ctrl2"
      })
      .state("state3", {
        url: "#",
        template: routeTemplate1,
        controller: "Ctrl1"
      });
});

var ctrls = angular.module("AppCtrls", []);

ctrls.controller( "Ctrl1", function($scope) {
    console.log("Ctrl1 loaded.");
});

ctrls.controller( "Ctrl2", function($scope) {
    console.log("Ctrl2 loaded.");
});
```